# Singular value decomposition of Block Diagonal matrix.

Tags: matrix-decomposition, svd

I have numerically seen the SVD of a bock diagonal matrix to be equal to the SVDs of individual 'elements' stacked. That is the matrices U and V would again be block diagonal with the U and V of individual 'elements'. How do I prove this?

Also is this true for only block diagonal matrices or does it generalize?